# Apache Storm on windows 8 or ubuntu (VMware Player)?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, apache-storm

I want to set up Apache Storm on Windows 8 but I’m not sure whether this is the best choice and what would be needed to do this. Or would you recommend to set up Storm on a VM (VMware player) with Ubuntu instead? At the end I want to scale-out Apache Storm on the EC2 Cloud.

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use ubuntu on some form of virtual machine for several reasons.  First, it's always good to develop on at least a variant of the production OS.  Second, installs of server software are sometimes a bit complicated and invasive.  It often helps to use a virtual machine to isolate those changes from your system making it easier to throw the VM out and try again.  Also, as newer versions of, in this case, Storm come out, you can install those versions on a clean system without overloading your existing dev environments.  There are costs and you'll need a decent host system to handle to load.